# GradientTape in TF doesn't work for LSTM Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

SOLVED!

I have reproduced a simple example.

```
data        =     tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 114))
LSTM_output =     layers.LSTM(2,input_shape=(None,114))(data)         

Model = tf.keras.Model(
                        inputs=[data],
                        outputs=[LSTM_output],
                        name="SDF_Model"
                        )
```

```
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100, 114])
noise_y = tf.random.normal([2])

mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    output = Model(noise)
    loss = mse(output,noise_y)
grads = tape.gradient(loss, Model.trainable_variables)
grads
```

returns [None,None,None] for me.

I checked that it works for Dense Layers. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

I was using an outdated version of Tensorflow. I updated to Tensorflow 2.3 and the gradients appeared.